# Помогите сообразить полноценный WHERE Builder

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, шаблоны-проектирования

Доброго времени суток!

Пишу небольшой класс для расширения работы с MySQLi.

Собственно помощь нужна в следующем:
Не могу написать грамотно функцию построения where оператора.

Мне нужно, чтобы он был максимально гибким, сейчас поясню.

Допустим имея массив:

```
array(

   'or' => array('login' => 'Admin', 'mail' => 'admin@glaz.com'),
   'or' => array('like' => array('login' => 'A%'), 'mail' => 'sss@glaz.com'),
   'login' => 'Stas Mikhailov'

);
```

Я получил следующий SQL запрос:

```
WHERE (login = Admin OR mail = admin@glaz.com) AND (login LIKE A% OR mail = sss@glaz.com) AND login = Stas Mikhailov
```

Теперь немного поясню, что я хочу: Есть массив, если в нем встречается массив с именем or, то строить так:

```
(key = value OR key2 = value2)
```

Если встречается массив like, то соответственно строить:

```
key LIKE value
```

Если никаких массивов нет, объединять все с помощью AND.

У меня уже голова гудит от этого, никак не могу получить желаемый результат.
Вот, что я пытался мудрить с OR и AND:

```
public function where($array = null) {

        if(!empty($array) && is_array($array)) {

            foreach($array as $key => $value) {

                if(is_array($value)) {

                    $separator = strtolower($key);
                    $separator = 'or' ? 'OR' : 'AND';

                    foreach($value as $key_array => $value_array) {

                        $key_array = $this->filter($key_array);
                        $value_array = $this->filter($value_array);
                        $where_array[] = '`'.$key_array.'` = "'.$value_array.'"';

                    }

                    $where[] = '('.implode(' '.$separator.' ', $where_array).')';

                } else {

                    $key = $this->filter($key);
                    $value = $this->filter($value);
                    $where[] = '`'.$key.'` = "'.$value.'"';

                }

            }

            $this->where = ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where);

        } else {

            die($this->class.': Параметры не определены (WHERE)');

        }

    }
```

Comment: Посмотрите на класс PDO http://php.net/manual/ru/class.pdo.php, а если нужно кастомизировать, то создайте дочерний класс. Не стоит изобретать очередной кривой велосипед.

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer Первый кривой лесапед - это PDO?

Comment: @Dmitry On gamer зачем мне PDO? Я же написал, что задача расширить класс mysqli. Есть ли конкретное решение моей задачи от вас? Не пойму куда рыть дальше...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Гибкий WHERE Builder написан.

```
public function where($array = null, $w = 'AND') {

        if(!empty($array) && is_array($array)) {

            foreach($array as $key => $value) {

                if(is_array($value)) {

                    $separator = strtoupper($key);

                    switch($separator) {

                        case 'OR':

                            $where[] = '('.$this->where($value, 'OR').')';

                        break;

                        case '>':
                        case '<':
                        case '<>':
                        case '>=':
                        case '<=':
                        case 'LIKE':

                            foreach($value as $key_array => $value_array) {

                                if(isset($key_array[$value_array])) {

                                    $key_array = $this->filter($key_array);
                                    $value_array = $this->filter($value_array);
                                    $where[] = '`'.$key_array.'` '.$separator.' "'.$value_array.'"';

                                } else {

                                    $error = true;

                                }

                            }

                        break;

                        case 'BETWEEN':
                        case 'IN':

                            foreach($value as $key_array => $value_array) {

                                if(is_array($value_array)) {

                                    $key_array = $this->filter($key_array);

                                    $where[] = '`'.$key_array.'` '.$separator.' ("'.implode('", "', $value_array).'")';

                                } else {

                                    $error = true;

                                }

                            }

                        break;

                        default:

                            $where[] = '('.$this->where($value, 'AND').')';

                        break;

                    }

                    if($error == true) {

                        $this->error_msg('Неверный синтаксис (Оператор "'.$separator.'")');

                    }

                } else {

                    $key = $this->filter($key);
                    $value = $this->filter($value);
                    $where[] = '`'.$key.'` = "'.$value.'"';

                }

            }

            $where = implode(' '.$w.' ', $where);
            $this->where = $where;

            return $where;

        } else {

            $this->error_msg('Параметры не определены (WHERE)');

        }

    }
```